# Dynamic programming for a complete binary tree

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to apply dynamic programming on a complete binary tree with 15 nodes, where each node is of type Employee and has a value(Evalution_Score) of type double and an ID.

I created an array of type double to store the max values. The method find returns the node with ID = j or I

```
public class BT<T> {
    BTNode<T> root, current;

    public BT() {
        root = current = null;
    }

    public void max(){
       BTNode<Employee> tmproot = (BTNode<Employee>)root;
       BTNode<Employee> tmp=null;
       double x[] = new double[33];
       Employee p[] = new Employee[33];

       for(int i=14;i>=0;i--) {
           tmp = search(i+1, tmproot);
           x[i] = Math.max(x[i+1], (tmp.data.Evaluation_Score + x[i+2+2]));
       }

       for(int j=14;j>=0;j--) {
           tmp = search(j+1, tmproot);
       if(x[j+1]<x[j])
           p[j] = tmp.data;
       }

       for(Employee e: p)
       System.out.println(e);
    }

    public BTNode<Employee> search(int id, BTNode<Employee> node){
        if(node != null){
            if(node.data.ID ==id){
               return node;
            } else {
                BTNode<Employee> foundNode = search(id, node.left);
                if(foundNode == null) {
                    foundNode = search(id, node.right);
                }
                return foundNode;
             }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class BTNode <T> {
    public T data;
    public BTNode<T> left, right;

    /** Creates a new instance of BTNode */
    public BTNode(T val) {
        data = val;
        left = right = null;
    }

    public BTNode(T val, BTNode<T> l, BTNode<T> r){
        data = val;
        left = l;
        right = r;
    }
}
```

---

```
class Employee {
    int ID_of_parent;
    String Name;
    int ID;
    double Evaluation_Score;

    public Employee(int ID_of_parent , String Name , int ID , double Evaluation_Score) {
        this.ID_of_parent = ID_of_parent;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.ID = ID;
        this.Evaluation_Score = Evaluation_Score;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ID_of_parent + ":" + Name + ":" + ID + ":" + Evaluation_Score + "\n";
    }
}
```

But for some reason it's not printing the required output exactly.

Comment: What this  code for? ->  x[I+2+2]  (i+2+2) => ?? , I believe it should be i*2+2

Comment: @cricket_007 Edited.

Comment: @IshaAgarwal Doesn't work

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm sorry, done.

Comment: Thanks! It's still not clear what the "required output" is supposed to be, though